# Why are the child elements inheriting the parent accessibility identifier?

Tags: swift, xcuitest, xcuielement

I have this view (and accessibility identifier):

```
private var carStack: some View {
    CarSwiftUIView(viewModel: viewModel.carViewModel)
        .accessibilityIdentifier("car")
        .accessibilityElement(children: .ignore)
}
```

If I use `.ignore` or `.contain`, the child elements within the `CarSwiftUIView` have the same named accessibility identifiers (`car`) as what's specified above.

Using `.combine`, I think, gives every child element the same identifier by default.

How can I make it so there's a parent accessibility identifier of `car`, and then within that view, I can name the child elements with different identifiers?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They were inheriting the parent's accessibilityIdentifier because they're not strictly "children". They are elements which form part of the parent's view.